# What happened to the "give skull" command in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I just got Minecraft Bedrock Edition, and I wanted to Make a map for a Minecraft YouTuber and put his head in the dedication, but both of the the "give skull" commands (`/give @p minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"_________"}` or `/give @p minecraft:skull {SkullOwner:"_________"}`)
isn't working. When I type in the former, it says "Missing Object Name" or something like that. But when I type in the Latter, it says something like "Item Not Recognized". Can anyone tell me what happened to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bedrock Edition doesn't have any NBT access with commands, so you can't `/give` items with extra data. They are planning a "component" system to do some of the things NBT does, but there's not much there yet.

Bedrock Edition also doesn't have player skulls, because it doesn't have skin servers. Skins are stored on the player's computer only, so there's no real way for them to add player skulls without a restructure of how that works.

The commands you have, and most commands you find online, are for Java Edition (the original version of the game). In Java Edition 1.12 and below your first command is fine. For Java Edition 1.13 and above you should use:

```
/give @s player_head{SkullOwner:"Notch"}
```

Comment: Really? Thanks for the info. I am kind of disappointed.

Comment: Also, I have used NBT tags in Bedrock Edition before when I played at my friend's house, and they worked. I used the command: 

/give @s diamond_sword 1 0 {display:{Name:"Super Sword"},lore:["A Good Blue Sword Never Breaks"]},{Unbreakable:1}

so this can't be true. Bedrock does have NBT access.

Comment: @ShadowBlstrTheNinja That has never worked on Bedrock edition. What you were playing at your friend's house will not have been Bedrock.

Comment: I have done it before. and it was on console. it was the new version on the Nintendo switch.

Comment: Oh, maybe that was just a dream. My bad! Anyways, could you inform me when they finnish the component system?